# Uploading directly to canvas with HTML5 (IE friendly)

Tags: internet-explorer, file-upload, html5-canvas

I am working on a webpage where users can upload images into a canvas element (no information is saved to the server).  Right now I have the upload being triggered by drag and drop functionality similar to this: http://hacks.mozilla.org/2011/01/how-to-develop-a-html5-image-uploader/

The problem is that certain browsers, notably IE, are not comparable with this functionality.  Therefore I would like to have the drag and drop area reduce to a a standard upload box (like a typical form file element), except still having it go directly to the canvas element (so no info being saved to server).  Is this possible?

Thanks.

Comment: This also seems like it would be useful for IOS6 devices, which can upload photos.

Answer (score 0):

There is little point in providing an upload to canvas on a browser that does not support the canvas element.  These are HTML5 elements. You need to use a plugin (flash etc.) to provide backward compatibility.